# UIWebView reveal webpage upon launch of application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, uiwebview

I'm trying to launch a URL with the `UIWebView` upon launch of my Mac application.

I started out with this,

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

With that, I get two errors that I can't figure out.

1. (ViewController.h) *`@interface ViewController : UIViewController {`*

   - **Error** - `Cannot find interface decleration 'UIViewController', superclass of 'ViewController'`
2. (ViewController.m) *`- (void)viewDidLoad {`*

   - **Error** - `Missing context for method declaration`

I'm not really familiar with is and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For OSX app, you don't have `UIViewController`, instead, you have `NSWindowController` and `NSViewController`, check [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/).

Comment: Okay, I'm using NSViewController now and the build succeeded. Do you think it's okay to call upon the ViewController class from the WebView now?

Comment: Logically, why not? between, I'm specialist in iOS applications not OSX application, so I can't direct you to the right way, but, you can download some book/tutorials on developing an OSX apps.

Comment: Okay, I tried that but it didn't work. What's strange is it builds but then generates errors...

Comment: For _any_ code. :-) You said it builds but generates errors, which could mean a million different things. If you can paste in the error messages you're getting, it'll be easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

**You are using IOS functions instead of OSX.**

Try this

In youy .h file

```
#import  <WebKit/WebKit.h>


  WebView *myWebView;
```

In your .m file

```
- (void)windowDidLoad

{

       NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
       NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];


}
```

**Don't forget to include "webkit.framework"**

Comment: Didn't work for me. But I feel like I'm missing something though, NSObject maybe? But that's not declared in the code...

Comment: I'm still not getting any response with the WebView after launch. I'm using the current code above and I've played around with it a bit. Has this worked for you by any chance?